# Subspaces - relation between images of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $S:V\rightarrow V$ are linear maps and Im(S) is a subset of Im(T) and rank(T)=rank(S) then is Im(T)=Im(S) necessarily?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If $U_1$ and $U_2$ subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space and if

$U_1 \subseteq U_2$ and $\dim U_1= \dim U_2$, then $U_1=U_2$.

Comment: Is there a simple proof?